# Locking access to /user redirect if logged out

Tags: 7, redirection, users

We have a Drupal 7 site that uses a bespoke login module for ordinary users. Certain (administrative) user rôles, however, must use the core login form at `/user` to log in, as they have escalated privileges. Regular users get a login form at `/` (redirected from any URL when not logged in) and cannot log in at `/user`; administrative users cannot log in at `/`, but must use the form at `/user` — these two forms ask different login questions.

We would like to be able to restrict the `/user` login form to a whitelist of IP addresses, so that only users coming from known IPs can use this form to log in. This would seem simple, at a first glance, as we could use Apache to reject requests for `^/user$` coming from non-whitelisted IPs, except that Drupal also uses `/user` as a redirect to the currently-logged-in users's profile page and this link appears in a handful of locations in our site.

Now I don't want to go hacking through Core, but I can't see how I can enforce the whitelist for anonymous users, whilst allowing any authenticated user to access their own profile page on the URL `/user`.

Should I go through everywhere that we link to `/user` (including the menu block) to substitute in the user's profile ID, or is there some more-elegant solution that I'm just not seeing?

All suggestions gratefully received  :o)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is necessarily the 'best' way to handle this but you could override the access callback for the `user` and `user/login` paths in a custom module and do your whitelist check in there:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_access_callback';
  $items['user/login']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_access_callback';
}

function MYMODULE_access_callback() {
  global $user;

  if ($user->uid) {
    // If a logged in user is trying to access the login page, deny access
    if (arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == 'login') {
      return FALSE;
    }

    // Otherwise let the user see their page
    return TRUE;
  }

  // If we've got this far the user is not logged in and the access
  // is based on the whitelist
  $whitelist = get_whitelist_array();
  if (in_array(ip_address(), $whitelist)) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```